# Why do we need PySpark, if Python-written scripts can be launched in standard Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Why do we need PySpark, if Python-written scripts can be launched in standard Spark?

I don't know Scala language, so, to work with Spark I installed PySpark (by using pip). But after some experiments with PySpark curiosity drove me to try launch Python script that I'm using (built-in ALS-based recommend engine) in standard Spark (not PySpark version). I did it by using "$ ./bin/spark-submit app.py".

And it works! Now I am confused: why do we need PySpark then?

Thank for your attention.

Comment: PySpark is a RELP to work interactively with Spark from Python. On the other hand, when you submit a job you do not have any way to interact with it. BTW, internally both the shell and the submit uses the same internals of Spark for Python. That is what you would call PySpark. - Your installed PySpark with pip is unnecessary for a cluster, but works for a development point of view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So, if I get it right:

1) PySpark just allows a user to use Spark features from standard Python environment, like any other Python app (launch it from notebooks, from Python shell ("$ python3 app.py")). It's can be easier for someone to develop a project, test it faster, check something.
2) Standard Spark can launch a Python app only by using "spark-submit", which can be overkill for just development, if you want to test something, make experiments, iterate etc. So on deployment the best practice is use standard Spark in any cases, right?

Comment: Yes. For deployment it is always recommended to use spark-submit with an appropriate scheduler _(like YARN on an standard Hadoop cluster)_ - note that Spark can be the scheduler too, that is useful if you have a spark-only cluster. Disclaimer: I am far from being an expert with Spark and less with PySpark. So, maybe someone else can give you a more detailed answer to your original question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, this is useful information. Good luck.